# Selenium doesn't open the browser in Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, debian

I'm new in Python and I'm trying to use Selenium in Debian but it doesn't work, more concretely it seems to stay in a loop and nothing happens. The next script is the test that I've used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://www.python.org')
```

When I interrupt the script the following text appears:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "prueba_parseo.py", line 7, in  browser =
>   webdriver.Firefox()   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py",
>   line 154, in **init**
>       keep_alive=True)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 140, in **init**
>       self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 229, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 295, in execute
>       response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py",
>   line 464, in execute
>       return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py",
>   line 488, in _request
>       resp = self._conn.getresponse()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1111, in getresponse
>       response.begin()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 444, in begin
>       version, status, reason = self._read_status()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 400, in _read_status
>       line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
>       data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
>
> KeyboardInterrupt

I've been searching for an answer, but nothing works. I've changed the versions of the packages, export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1"

OS: Debian 5

Python: 2.7

Selenium: 3.5

Geckodriver: 0.17.0

Firefox: 52.0

I don't know what else to do or what to change.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Please confirm your Firefox 52 are compatible with Geckodriver 0.17.0 and Selenium 3.5,   I use chrome in most time in case you want to try on chrome,  my chrome is 60, chromedriver is 2.30,  selenium 3.4.0.  I think selenium 3.5.0 should be ok.

Comment: Yes, they are compatible. Maybe I should change the browser and try with chrome.

Comment: I've found the answer. The problem was that I was launching the script remotely and not from the local computer.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it actually all goes well and the browser is started in background. The reason why it's staying open is probably because of the default option `keep_alive=True` I can see in your traceback.

Try closing the browser using `browser.close()` or `browser.quit()` when you are done with the tests.

From the documentation:

> Finally, the browser window is closed. You can also call quit method
>   instead of close. The quit will exit entire browser whereas close`
>   will close one tab, but if just one tab was open, by default most
>   browser will exit entirely.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage

Comment: Still staying in the loop, nothing changes and the same text appears. It looks like the problem comes from webdriver but I don't know why.

Comment: "keep_alive=True" is not the reason